# jQuery DataTables show processing message after ESC on print

Tags: datatables

I cannot seem to get rid of the Processing message that wants to display after the ESC is pressed during the print function.  I am using 1.10.11.  I do not want to remove the message completely, I want it to show during the load of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the dataTables.tableTools.js file in _fnPrintEnd function like this:

```
 var that = this;
    var oSetDT = this.s.dt;
    var tbl = this.s.dt.nTable.id;
    $("#" + tbl + "_processing").css("visibility", "hidden");
    var oSetPrint = this.s.print;
    var oDomPrint = this.dom.print;
```

Added the processing hidden command.

Answer (score 0):

The *Processing...* message appears when the client is waiting for a server response to an AJAX request. When a print is opened and then left (with the ESC key), the server must re-send the data to the client.

The first FAQ on the DataTables website under the Server-Side Processing category is

> Q: It's not working... (stuck on *Processing*)
>
> A: This is usually down to incorrect JSON data being passed back from the server. Please refer to [this technical note](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1) on how to debug and resolve this issue.

To summarize what is in that technical note, basically the idea is that the JSON requested from the server is not being sent back correctly. Either there is a minor typo/error in the format or you have forgotten some field(s). If that's not your issue, the next FAQ question is

> Q. It's still not working...
>
> A. The next most common reason for server-side processing not working is the draw variable not being returned as it was set in the request. DataTables uses draw to keep a draw count, so this is an important parameter. See [server-side usage](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

That page outlines the details of what data needs to be sent in the JSON, but the most important one to note is the `draw` option. The description from the documentation (for the draw parameter sent from client to server) is:

> Draw counter. This is used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables (Ajax requests are asynchronous and thus can return out of sequence). This is used as part of the draw return parameter.

and the return `draw` parameter is

> The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the draw parameter sent as part of the data request. Note that it is strongly recommended for security reasons that you cast this parameter to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in the draw parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

To summarize all that: the first thing you should check is that your JSON being sent to and from the server is of the correct format and is free of errors. The author of the plugin recommends JSONLint to debug your JSON. If your JSON is of the correct format and error-free, the next thing to take a look at is your `draw` parameter; make sure that each request to the server uses a new `draw` value and that the server sends back a matching `draw` parameter when the data is returned.

Also, I'd recommend checking out those two documentations linked above if you are still having trouble with the JSON, as they are very detailed and describe exactly what is needed.

**Disclaimer:** If you're not using server-side processing this is all moot, but since it is such a common issue for server-side processing users, I think it's safe to assume you are.

**Edit:** Check out [this forum post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/3832/#Comment_3832) where Allan Jardine (the plugin creator) mentions the server-side request when a print is done. This makes sense because the processing tag appears between when the ajax request has been sent and the ajax response is received.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the problem I have is returning from a PRINT to the table with the ESC key and the processing message shows and shouldn't

Comment: Are you using server-side processing at all though? If you are, then when you return from a print the table tries to get reloaded, and if either of the above two issues occur during the reload that would cause you to get stuck with the processing message.

Comment: No I am not using server side processing.  How do I get around this?